# Incorrect privilege wiki for the 10k tools (Privilege descriptions out of date)

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges

On the page `[Privileges - Access to moderator tools][1]`

---

What is moderation?

As one of our most experienced users, we're counting on you to guide the community and lead by example.

You have earned the **highest level** of privilege in our community -- short of being elected a community moderator. You can ...

---

Bummer. Another 10k to go..

Comment: Just means that the team needs to push the MSO privileges page out to the other sites, since ours is editable, considered the master one, and was updated 5 days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per waiwai933's comment and some time between that comment and this answer, the push happened and all is well again.

This answer brought to you courtesy of the recommendation by Grace here https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80263/156011