# What do you do with "expired" questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, answers

For example, see my question here:

[Incorrect privilege wiki for the 10k tools (Privilege descriptions out of date)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79465/incorrect-privilege-wiki-for-the-10k-tools-privilege-descriptions-out-of-date)
<sub>Surprisingly, I got another vote just minutes ago on that question..</sub>

It has been expired since the update some time last week (?) has corrected it. Do I delete it? Vote to close it (10K users will zoom in and close it right?)?

Or should I make an answer and accept it, so that it can be "closed" by way of being "accepted"?

What is the norm or correct way to deal with these questions?

Answer (score 4):

For a feature request or bug that gets directly resolved but doesn't get an answer or even tag revision from the Team, post what led to its resolution as an answer. Subsequently, either hope for a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) to be added in response to your bump, or flag a moderator to do so.

Minor bug reports tend to be cleared up over time, so don't be surprised if, at some point down the line, the report might vanish. But there's no telling when this kind of cleaning will happen or when it will be needed, so deleting it on your own is generally not as useful as just noting the resolution.

If the question is expired because changes *invalidated* the original question, then it still doesn't hurt to answer it. But it's not *too* bad to just eliminate it, if it's referring to something outdated that'll just confuse people by being brought up.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Grace Note said, I tend to vote to close as Too Localized — with varying degrees of success — and flag for mod attention with a message along the lines of "Needs to be tagged [status-completed]."

Comment: That makes it appear as if the question led to the change - in this case it didn't